# Show that, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist two rationals such that $q < x < q'$ and $|q-q'|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

I think I have the first part, as I have shown that $q < q + (q'-q)/2 < q'$, but I have trouble in proving that $|q-q'|< \epsilon$.  Could someone tell me if there is a better way of showing the first part and how to show the second part?

For those asking x is a real number

Comment: Given $x$, how do you come up with $q,q'$?

Comment: What is $x$? I'm guessing irrational?

Comment: @graydad The result is true even for rational $x$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes, but I want to be specific about what OP needs to show.

Comment: @graydad If you can prove the more general result using the same argument, then I don't think it matters.

Comment: @graydad x is real

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the decimal expansion of $x$. For example, suppose that $x = \pi$, and so $x=3.14159\ldots$. Suppose we're interested in an error of at most $10^{-5}$. Then we can take $q=3.14159 < x$ and $q' = 3.13160 > x$. Generalize.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can use the fact that given $a,b \in \Bbb R$ with $a < b$, there is a rational number between $a$ and $b$. Then see how you can use this fact.